# Numerical Solution to 3 Dimensional Backward BS PDE

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde, finite-difference-method, parabolic-pde, finite-difference

I have a three dimensional backward BS PDE.

$$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + a(t) S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma(t, S)^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + b(t, M) \frac{\partial V}{\partial M} + c \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} - rV = 0$$

with the terminal condition $V(T, S, M, \phi) = g(S, M, \phi)$

If I try to apply a Crack Nicholson method

$$2 \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{f(t+1, x_{i+1}) - f(t+1, x_i)}{\delta x} + \frac{f(t, x_{i+1}) - f(t, x_{i})}{\delta x}$$

to $S$, $M$ and $\phi$ the equation gets too complicated to solve.

So, should I only apply this to the $S$ variable and approximate the derivatives for $M$ and $\phi$ only usingw backward time values? How would you approach this?

Comment: What do you mean too complicated to solve? To complicated for you to write down, the computer computes this too slowly, memory explodes, unstable, impossible to debug, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look on Alternating Direction Implicit for solving multi-dimension PDE on finite difference method. The linear system will still be tridiagonal matrix.